# I'm trying to understand bash's mapping format

Tags: bash

What exactly do these mapping strings mean, ie. "\e[5C" ... I understand that I can jump words with the key combos mentioned in the comment but I am trying to understand how to read mappings in this format.

```
# mappings for Ctrl-left-arrow and Ctrl-right-arrow for word moving

"\e[1;5C": forward-word
"\e[1;5D": backward-word
"\e[5C": forward-word
"\e[5D": backward-word
"\e\e[C": forward-word
"\e\e[D": backward-word
```

Comment: `\e` means "escape", aka ASCII 27.  Everything means exactly what it says.

Comment: what do you mean everything means exactly what it says? Why would someone press [1;5C to go forward one word when you can press alt + F?

Comment: A *person* wouldn't necessarily, but your terminal may send those keycodes in response to various keys.  For example, on my system, left arrow sends `\e[D` and right arrow sends `\e[C`.  And of course, typing `alt-F` results in `\eF`.